# my class isn't working when I go to change the colour

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, and I am trying to change the colour and size of my button. However, my styles do not appear to be getting applied. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<button class="dropbtn">Menu!</button>
```

Comment: <button class="dropbtn">Menu!</button> this is the code!!!

Comment: Please include the css too. It would also be useful to show where your css is being linked.

Comment: Post the code you use to change the color. All you posted was some plain HTML.

Comment: All sorted now! I made a mistake with the html, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this into the head tags of your html document, or add it to your css file.

```
<style>
.dropbtn {
    color: #333;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @WorstForum The questions was not great, and you just got stuck in the middle. Plus I think they downvoted you because you recommended the use of important instead of being more specific in your selectors.